# Spring Data JPA repositories not being auto-created with CommandLineRunner

Tags: spring, groovy, spring-data, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to write a simple Spring Data JPA app for Spring Boot in Groovy. I followed the [getting started guide](http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/) and did some basic transformation to make it work with Groovy and the Spring Boot CLI.

I am running the code with the Spring Boot CLI (v1.1.8):

```
spring run app.groovy
```

This results in the error:

```
NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [hello.CustomerRepository] is defined
```

Does anyone have an idea why the Repository is not getting created automatically? I feel like I must be missing something simple. Here is the app.groovy file containing *all* of the code:

```
package hello

@Grab("spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
@Grab("h2")

import java.util.List
import javax.persistence.*
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository

@Entity
class Customer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    long id
    String name

    Customer() {}
    Customer(String name) {
        this.name = name
    }
}

interface CustomerRepository extends CrudRepository<Customer, Long> {
    List<Customer> findByName(String name)
}

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    ConfigurableApplicationContext context

    void run(String[] args) {
        CustomerRepository repository = context.getBean(CustomerRepository.class)
        repository.save(new Customer("Jack", "Bauer"))
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried adding `@EnableJpaRepositories`

Comment: Yes, I have tried adding the @EnableJpaRepositories to the Application class. It did not change the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Groovy CLI app can only scan for JPA repositories if you give it actual classes (i.e. not the .groovy scripts). You can build a jar file and run that, and it should work:

```
$ spring jar app.jar app.groovy
$ java -jar app.jar
```